# mySQL store file details in one or many database table design and best way of creating parent and child categories

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, left-join

----- PHP and mySQL -----

I have two quick questions need some advice.

On my site I will allow users to upload following files -  PDF/Videos/Photos. All files uploaded by the user are shown on a profile page. All uploaded files can be searched by name or tags and file type.

What would be the best mysql database design?

1. Store all files in one table, easier to display on user’s profile page and searching by type and etc.
2. One table per type e.g. pdf, videos and photos <- this might be better for performance but for searching I don’t know?

Second question is, I allow users to create their own menus/categories with parent and children  categories for example:

- ->parent category
- - - - > child category
- - - - > child category
- ->parent category
- - - - > child category
- - - - > child category

At moment I have two database tables, one stores all the parent categories for each user and second store child category with foreign key (id) to parent category.

To get all the categories I first get all the parent categories and using a foreach loop.
I call a function  within the loop to get the children categories by parent id.

I want to know is this the best approach of doing this or can this be done in mySQL query without looping?

thanks guys !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, it depends on what information you want to store about the files.

If it's generic across all types, (name, date, filetype, size, etc.) then a single Files  table by itself with a type column makes sense.

But if you're going to save attributes of the files that have to do with what kind of file they are, frame rate of a video file, height and width of an image file, author of a PDF, for example, then you will also need some ancillary tables to store that information.  You don't want to have a bunch of columns hanging off your file table that are only useful each for a certain file type.

For your second question, the rough SQL is based on a JOIN between your parent category table and your child category tables.

Example psuedo code:

```
select p.userid, p.parentcategoryid,c.childcategoryid 
from ParentCategory p INNER JOIN   
     ChildCategory c  
        on p.parentcategoryid=c.parentcategoryid
WHERE 
      p.userid = @UserID
```

Comment: thanks. regarding first answer, Say if their were over 1millon records stored in this one table the search would be slow. i am thinking of  breaking the single table into three separate tables e.g a table for pdf/photos/videos in this case if the users want to search all file type, i do union all search. would this be a better approach ?

Comment: Depends on the query.  If the table is indexed properly, a million rows shouldn't be a problem to query quickly.